# Let $X_n>0$ be iid and $P(X_n>t)\sim t^{-\alpha}$, show that $Y_n=n^{-1/\alpha}S_n$ and $1/Y_n$ are tight.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We are given that $X_n>0$ be iid with common distribtuon $X$, and $P(X>t)\sim t^{-\alpha}$, I need to show that the scale of $Y_n$ is $n^{1/\alpha}$. Or in other words show that $Y_n=n^{-1/\alpha}S_n$ and $1/Y_n$ are tight.

Here is my attempt so far: Let $\epsilon>0$, the goal is to find a $t$ big enough so that $P(Y_n>t)<\epsilon$ for all $n$. We also define $M_n=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i$.

\begin{align}
P(Y_n>t)&=P(n^{-1/\alpha} S_n>t)\leq P(n^{-1/\alpha}nM_n>t)=P(M_n>tn^{1/\alpha-1})
\end{align}

We have that $$P(M_n>t)=1-(1-P(X>t))^n\sim 1-(1-t^{-\alpha})^n$$

Thus $$P(Y_n>t)\leq P(M_n>tn^{1/\alpha-1})\sim 1-(1-t^{-\alpha}n^{\alpha-1})^n$$

And I am unsure of where to go form here. Any ideas? I am even less sure of what to show that $1/Y_n$ are tight.

Comment: [Tight, tight, tight.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgUi4easWL8&feature=youtu.be&t=19s)

Comment: Haha that is the first thing that came to my mind as well :p

Comment: What are $S_n$ and $Y_n$?

Comment: $S_n = \sum_{i \leq n} X_i$ is typical.

Comment: $Y_n=n^{-1/\alpha}S_n$

Comment: can we use that $(1-t^{-\alpha}n^{\alpha-1})^n$ goes to 1 as t grows when $\alpha>0$?